# Extend interface from another - MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, eslint

I have an interface

```
interface ThemeBase {
  colors: {
    [key: string]: Color;
  };
  borderRadius: {
    base: string;
    mobile: string;
  };
  navbar: {
    'z-index': number;
  };
  typography: {
    rootBase: string;
    fontBase: string;
  };
}
```

And I want to extend MUI theme with this interface.
This solution work for me:

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface Theme extends ThemeBase {}
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions extends ThemeBase {}
}
```

But I have an error from eslint

> error  An interface declaring no members is equivalent to its
>   supertype  @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface

How to fix this without code duplication for Theme and ThemeOptions

Comment: `type Theme = ThemeBase` maybe?

Comment: no, this work in common case but not with Material UI (

Comment: Have you actually tried it? According to the spec that should work (don't have a playground available)

Comment: yes, I am trying to create a playground now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those few examples where it's completely fine IMO to just put `/* eslint-ignore @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface */` in the first line. While I wouldn't do it in regular code, module augmentation is a bit of a different beast, there's no point trying to find a workaround here.